# Can we prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (a_1 a_2\cdots a_n)=0$ by $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$?

Tags: calculus

Can we prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (a_1 a_2\cdots a_n)=0$ by $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$? Or just give a counterexample that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (a_1 a_2\cdots a_n)=0$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\neq 0$?

Comment: "Or just give a counterexample..." What you wrote down in this sentence would not be a counterexample to the original statement.

Comment: For large n, we have |Product(a_i)| <|a_n|. Since |a_n| goes to 0, so does |Product(a_i)|.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u_n=a_1\cdots a_n$. If one of $a_i=0$ then the result is clear. Otherwise, and since

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=a_{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so by the ratio test $\sum u_n$ is convergent and in particular $\lim u_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. In particular, there exists $N>0$ such that $|a_n|<1/2$ for all $n\ge N$. Set $C:=|a_1\cdots a_N|$. This implies that
$$
|a_1\cdots a_{N+n}| \le \frac{C}{2^n} \to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

There exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n|<1$, Write $M=a_1...a_N$, this implies that for $p>0$, $|a_1....a_Na_{N+1}...a_{N+p}|\leq M|a_{N+1}...a_{N+p}|\leq M|a_{N+p}|$, for every $c>0$, take $p_0$ such that for every $p>p_0, |a_{N+p}|<cM$ you deduce that for $p>p_0, |a_1...a_{N+p}|<c$.